# Xcode 7 - custom UITableViewController no longer drawing in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I created a UITableViewController in my storyboard. Added all the table cells, etc. and set it up with a Custom UITableViewController. But now, when I open my Storyboard, the image of the ViewController no longer draws. There is a segue drawn from the calling controller, but it just points to empty space.

The original controller entry can be found on the left in the "document outline" with all of its subviews and constraints intact, and I can run the app on my iPad without a problem.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and is there a recovery action I can take to get the controller to draw in the storyboard?

[image: Storyborad-Missing UIViewController drawing]

Comment: Please add an image, So we can understand better

Comment: Added Image of Storyboard with missing UIViewController.